# SVN tag version number increment from the command line

Tags: regex, svn, shell

Well I wanted to know if I could get the latest tag from subversion, increment it and create the new tag all in one command? Currently I get the latest tag like this:

```
svn ls http://svn/path/to/tags | tail -n 1
```

Which gives me something like this:

```
1.2.34/
```

then I will create a new tag with the version number of 1.2.35 as I've incremented the version number like this:

```
svn copy http://svn/path/to/trunk http://svn/path/to/tags/1.2.35
```

from here I just do a switch to point production code to the latest tag.

I know I could write a script to take care of this but I wanted to know if I could do this just from the command line with one command (Chaining the commands). Were I'm stuck is, how do I increment the tag name to the next version number (e.g., from 1.2.34 to 1.2.35)? Version number ranges should follow `x.[0-99].[0-99]`. Any ideas, help would be great.

Related:

- http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/browse

Comment: I can't think of a way to do this in a single command line, but I'd imagine that if it was possible, it'd be so long and convoluted, you'd be more likely to make a mistake than simply writing a small shell script. I'm concerned whether or not your command is really pulling up the last version. For example, if you had `1.12.2` and `1.9.4`, your command would assume that `1.9.4` is later than `1.12.2` which isn't the case.

Comment: Why do you need a one-liner??? It's definitely a script, I'd implement it in perl (all, including svn copy and probably add more features there like checking tag).

Comment: I'd just do it manually - it's not a hardship unless you are versioning every 5 minutes.

Comment: @ChrisSmith: Anything in a release process should be automated. In a manual procedure, there's a good likelihood that you're going to do something wrong sooner or later and usually at the worst possible time.

Comment: Tagging is not part of the release process IMHO - it's a separate concept from which the release is driven.  Actually, we never tag on our deployments.  They are from the HEAD of a stable branch always and deployed through Team City.

Comment: I recently started tags are I like the concept of switching to a tag version for production, svn switch is awesome in conjunction with tags versions

Comment: @ChrisSmith - Production stuff is the only stuff we tag. We use Jenkins and Jenkins has the SVN revision used in a build, so we can always pull the correct source or branch at that point. Not all releases are at the head of a branch. We might create a REL-1.0 branch, then need a REL-1.0.1 hotfix. In that case, we do the new work off of the REL-1.0 branch. If we don't tag the REL-1.0 release, we lose which files went in it.

Comment: I started following this workflow. trunk->branch, make changes in branch and merge back into trunk when finished, trunk->tag, tag the trunk for production release, svn switch to tag, if err switch back to previous tag. So we cover all areas of development, testing, production. Starting to really like this method/structure as well

Comment: tail -n will **not** give biggest version in common case. I'll suggest to write gawk|perl script for getting|incrementing number and passing it to svn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "one liner" to get the next tag would be something like this:

```
svn ls http://svn/path/to/tags | \
  sort -t '.' -k 1,1n -k 2,2n -k 3,3n | \
  tail -1|sed 's:/$::' | \
  awk 'BEGIN{FS="."}{print $1 "." $2 "." $3+1}'
```

... but you should probably just write a script so that you can actually test it.  (And yes, I'm aware that the sort and tail and sed and awk could probably all collapse under its own weight into a bit of perl, but you'll need all those "parts" in there somewhere.)

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
svn copy http://svn/path/to/trunk http://svn/path/to/tags/`svn ls http://svn/path/to/tags | some-script-for-getting number`
```